# Assigning types to variables in Go

Tags: go

How to have a variable whose type is a variable type?

What do I mean by that? I have a python and java background. In both languages I can do things like assigning a class name to variable.

```
#Python
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "Some Value"

# And asigning the class name to a variable
class_A = A

# And create instance from class A by using class_A
a = class_A()
```

Is there such a mechanism in go that allows me to do that? I couldn't know where to look at for such things in their documentation. Honestly, generally I don't know what these are called in programming languages.

For example I would like to be able to do:

```
// For example, what would be the type of myType?
var myType type = int
```

I will use this mechanism to take "type" arguments. For example:

```
func Infer(value interface{}, type gotype) {...}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there such a mechanism in go that allows me to do that?

The short answer is: **No.**

The long answer is: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), so depending on what you're actually trying to accomplish, there may be a way. Jump to the end to see where I address your specific use-case.

I suspect that if you want to store a data type in a variable, it's because you either want to compare some other variable's type against it, or perhaps you want to create a variable of this otherwise unknown type. These two scenarios can be accomplished in Go.

In the first case, just use a type switch:

```
switch someVar.(type) {
    case string:
        // Do stringy things
    case int:
        // Do inty things
}
```

Semantically, this looks a lot like assigning the type of `someVar` to the implicit switch comparison variable, then comparing against various types.

In the second case I mentioned, if you want to create a variable of an unknown type, this can be done in a round-about way using reflection:

```
type := reflect.TypeOf(someVar)
newVar := reflect.New(type).Interface()
```

Here `newVar` is now an `interface{}` that wraps a variable of the same type as `someVar`.

In your specific example:

> I will use this mechanism to take "type" arguments. For example:
>
> ```
> func Infer(value interface{}, type gotype) {...}
> ```

No, there's no way to do this. And it actually has much less to do with Go's variable support than it does with the fact that Go is compiled.

Variables are entirely a runtime concept.  Function signatures (like all other types in Go) are fixed at compilation time.  It's therefore impossible for *runtime* variables to affect the compilation stage. This is true in any compiled language, not a special feature (or lack thereof) in Go.

Comment: I see what your saying but I do think this could be supported in Go if they really wanted to.

In F# for instance (a compiled language) it uses Discriminated Unions:

type MyType = Person|Place|Thing
type Something struct = { 
    Name string 
    MyObj MyType
}

While it may be syntactic sugar in F# it is extremely useful. 

Maybe I am misunderstanding?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there such a mechanism in go that allows me to do that?

No there is not.

Answer (score -1):

Use the  empty interface:

```c
var x, y interface{}
var a uint32
a = 255
x = int8(a)
y = uint8(a)
```

[Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/lYGWRHhT6Tm)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question asked how to assign the type itself to a variable, while the answer is assigning a variable to another variable.

Answer (score -2):

You mean like this?

```
var variableOfTypeByteArray []byte
```